# iptables: checking if a IP is blocked in firewall

Tags: iptables

If a IP is blocked in iptables by its "IP" it is easy to grep iptables like

```
iptables -L -n | grep "a.b.c.d"
```

but if the IP has been blocked using a IP range like :

```
iptables -A INPUT -s "163.172.000.000/16" -j DROP
```

well, then this method does not work any more. what method could be used?

Comment: I prefer to not have DROP for one IP address exactely to that point. I actually just drop everything except the open IP or ports, so I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ipaddr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) with python.

First you list the rules you are interested in with `iptables -S` (that will list single IPs as /32, which comes in handy):

Then you feed the blocks to this python script, `check_ip.py`. It checks if the first parameter (the address) belongs to the second parameter (the block) and exits with code 0 or 1.

```
#!/bin/python3

import ipaddress
import sys

sys.exit(ipaddress.ip_address(sys.argv[1]) in ipaddress.ip_network(sys.argv[2],strict=False))
```

You can then connect those two pieces.

The following is a quickly written bash command line, but you could also move the whole code to python, or use `xargs`, ...

iptables -S | grep DROP | awk '{print $4,$0}' | while read a b; do python3 check_ip.py IP.ADDR.TO.CHECK $a || echo $b; done

Comment: it is very slow but it works :))

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to precede the firewall rule with another rule designed to log such packet drops. Instead of:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s "163.172.000.000/16" -j DROP
```

The preferred way to reject traffic should be:

```
iptables -N logNdrop
iptables -A logNdrop -j LOG --log-level 5 --log-prefix 'Packet dropped: '
iptables -A logNdrop -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s "163.172.000.000/16" -j logNdrop
```

That will allow you to look for IP blocking occurrences in files such as `/var/log/messages`, depending on how your syslog daemon is configured:

```
# egrep 'Packet dropped: .* SRC=163.172.181.190 ' /var/log/messages
# tail -F /var/log/messages | egrep 'Packet dropped: .* SRC=163.172.181.190 '
```